# Поиск экстремальных значений списка (не максимального и минимального значения в списке) а последовательных экстремальных значений макс/мин

Tags: python, list

Загвоздка возникла в том что за период времени нужно посчитать максимальную просадку по эквити (баланс счёта). Имеем список в котором каждый элемент списка означает изменение баланса. Но так как нужно посчитать максимальную просадку за весь период (не путать с максимальным количеством подряд убыточных сделок) есть проблема как определить эту максимальную просадку.

Думал сделать так сначала найти все экстремальные значения перед тем как уровень эквити начал снижаться, а после минимальное значение на протяжение всего этого снижения.

Ниже код для поиска экстремальных значений до минимальных значений пока не добрался.

```
lst1 = []

for num in range(len(equity_result1)):
    if equity_result1[num-1]<equity_result1[num]>equity_result1[num+1] and equity_result1[num] > next (iter(equity_result1[0:num])):
        lst1.append(equity_result1[num])
    
print(lst1)
```

```
[15220.0, 21550.0, 34210.0, 37250.0, 56240.0, 65750.0, 78340.0, 95980.0, 127480.0, 158830.0, 190080.0, 182930.0, 208930.0, 204980.0, 214330.0, 239580.0, 283210.0, 311950.0, 349930.0, 341350.0]
```

как видно из списка есть значения которые меньше предыдущего чего быть не должно.

добавил так же что именно нужно посчитать.[image: "]

Comment: У вас проблема с алгоритмом или кодированием? На бумажке алгоритм работает нормально?

Comment: Возможно и с тем и с другим, но так как я вижу себе решение такой задачи, то проблема именно в коде реализовать. Я вижу алгоритм так  находим максимум он будет как n-1<n-max1>n+1 и таким же образом ищем минимум где n-1>n-min1<n+1 но поиск минимума мы ищем до тех пор пока не произойдёт событие что n-max1 < n-max...n. Далее все n-max1 - n-min1 соответственно так получаем набольшее значение который и определит максимальное отклонение. Момент в том что n-max1 может соответствовать несколько n-min1 пока не произойдёт событие n-max1 < n-max...n.

Comment: 1) ограничения по времени работы есть? (или там миллион клиентов с кучей счетов?) 2) Тестовый пример есть для `lst1`?

Comment: Вот посмотрите сюда - похоже на ваш случай, а то так долго будем обмениваться вопросами : <https://overcoder.net/q/517984/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python>